# How can I read the body from QNetworkReply if code is not 200

Tags: qt, qnetworkreply

Reply returns empty body content if `reply->error() != QNetworkReply::NoError`, 
but actually response has a content.

How can I read it?

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
   manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);

   connect( manager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),
            this, SLOT(replyFinished(QNetworkReply*)));

   manager->get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl("http://...")));
}

void MainWindow::replyFinished(QNetworkReply* reply)
{
  if (reply->error() == QNetworkReply::NoError)
    {
      QByteArray content= reply->readAll();
      QDebug() << QString body(content); // ok
    } else {
       QByteArray content= reply->readAll();
       QDebug() << QString body(content); //empty, but must be exist
    }
}
```

Comment: What does `reply->errorString()` returns on error?

Comment: Yes, it returns description of error code and nothing more.